# GitHub Actions conditions on step

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to run terraform linting using github action and can't figure out how to filter outputs. In first job, I return list of directories where terraform files are found. In second job, I need to have a condition where directories containing modules have `terraform init` ran against them . I tried 'if' statement to filter out only those directories but it seems the condition is ignored and the step is done for all directories.

```
jobs:
  collectInputs:
      name: Collect terraform directories
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      outputs:
        directories: ${{ steps.dirs.outputs.directories }}
      steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v2

        - name: Get root directories
          id: dirs
          uses: clowdhaus/terraform-composite-actions/directories@main

        - name: Outputs
          run: echo "${{ steps.dirs.outputs.directories}}"
  tflint:
    name: tflint
    needs: collectInputs
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        directory: ${{ fromJson(needs.collectInputs.outputs.directories) }}
    steps:
      - name: Clone repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: show only directory with 'module' substring
        if: contains("${{ matrix.directory }}", 'module')
        run: echo "This directory contains string 'module'"
```

Comment: I think you have too many $ out there. `if: contains(${{ matrix.directory }}, 'module')`. I would anyways advise for this case to filter out stuff on `collectInputs` level, instead of filtering - workflow logs will be easier to read than

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzKrukowski, I fixed the typo ( however this is just a typo and does not fix the issue). I am also leaning towards filtering out collectionInput as a workaround